# Proof of part of haversine formula?

Tags: distance, spherical-geometry

I'm trying to study how to find the distance between two points if their latitudes and longitudes are given.

I have a question about the proof of part of the haversine formula given at [Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103604/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html). It says that the length of chord AD, two points at the same latitude, lat1, on a sphere of radius 1, is

2*sin(dlon/2)*cos(lat1)

but I couldn't get how they obtained it. Could you help me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance or failing that Snyder http://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf

Comment: @iant:The link from Wikipedia is too hard to understand that's why I tried this:http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html. Could you cite where the proof of haversine formula is given in the US publication report.

Comment: @MartinF:I really mean _doubt_ as in question.Could you help me with figuring out how they obtained the length of **chord AD** as `2*sin(dlon/2)*cos(lat1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The radius, r, of the small circle joining all points at latitude, φ is

r = R cos φ

where R is the radius of the sphere. That simplifies to

r = cos φ

if we assume a "unit sphere" (R = 1) for convenience.

```
--------------------- A/D
|        r       φ /
|                 /
|                /
|               /
|a             /
|x            /
|i           /
|s          /
|          / R
|         /
|        /
|       /
|      /
|     /
|    /    ("side" view)
|   /
|  /
| /
|/ φ           equatorial radius
-----------------------------------------------
```

The chord length of a straight line, AD, joining two points on the same latitude is

AD = 2 r sin dλ/2

where dλ is the difference in longitude of A and D.  Thus

AD = 2 R cos φ sin dλ/2

or

AD = 2 cos φ sin dλ/2

if R = 1

```
A-----------------D
 \       |       /
  \      |      /
   \     |     /
    \    |    / r
     \   |   /
      \  dλ /
       \   /
        \ /

    ("top" view)
```

Comment: :Okay.That's a good answer.Could you tell me how did you obtained the equation for **chord AD** as `2rsind &lambda/2`.Really from where did `2r` come?

Comment: @justin: Half the chord is r sin dλ/2